# Why doesn't the number of occurences increase?

Tags: python, file, python-itertools

Here is my problem: I have a dictionary (`dico`) and I want to count the number of times, for 2 different keys, that they both appear on the same line in the file "file.tsv" which looks like this:

```
sp_345_4567 pe_645_4567876  ap_456_45678    pe_645_4556789 ...
sp_345_567  pe_645_45678 ...
pe_645_45678    ap_456_345678 ...
sp_345_56789    ap_456_345 ...
pe_645_45678    ap_456_345678 ...
sp_345_56789    ap_456_345 ...
...
```

For example, the values of the banana and apple keys appear on line 1 so no matter how many times they appear they are still present, and so we have 1 line in common, and I want to do it on all the lines of the file

For that I added the pattern `'_\w+'` behind each value and then made a regex with the function `re.search`.

```
from itertools import product
import csv

dico = {
    "banana": "sp_345",
    "apple": "ap_456",
    "pear": "pe_345",
    "cherry": "ap_345",
    "coco": "sp_543",
}

counter = {}
with open("file.tsv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")
    for line in reader:
        for key1, key2 in product(dico, dico):
            if key1 >= key2:
                continue
            counter[key1, key2] = 0
            k1 = k2 = False
            for el in line:
                if re.search(dico[key1]+'_\w+', el):
                    k1 = True
                elif re.search(dico[key2]+'_\w+', el):
                    k2 = True
                if k1 and k2:
                    counter[key1, key2] += 1
                    break

for key, val in counter.items():
    print(key, val)
```

But the occurrences is stop at 0:

```
Apple banana 0
pear banana 0
pear apple 0
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really clear what you're asking. What is your expected output? Are you trying to find all of the combinations of item pairs that appear on the same line and take a count of that? Can you truncate the input file in a way that still makes it usable in a [mcve]? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k1` and `k2` can't both be `True` because you are initializing both with `False` and setting at most one to `True`.

```
elif re.search(dico[key2]+'_\w+', el):
    k2 = True
```

should be

```
if re.search(dico[key2]+'_\w+', el):
     k2 = True
```